# How to retrieve overridden behavior in MOQ?

Tags: c#, moq

I'm wondering if it is possible to retrieve setup behavior and restore after it is overridden. In pseudo-code it could look like this:

```
mediator.Setup(m => m.Fetch(It.IsAny<Query>())).Returns(() => Action1()); // setup 1

// catch here setup 1

mediator.Setup(m => m.Fetch(It.IsAny<Query>())).Returns(() => Action2()); // setup 2

// restore setup 1 here
```

Do you see a solution?

Comment: I do not understand the question. Could you post the code under test and the test itself as well?

Comment: Last setup wins. That means that when ever you call setup is overrides the previous setup that matches. So basically what you have in you question is possible out of the box

Comment: Yes, last setup wins but I was asking if it is possible to keep first setup before overriding and then restore it later.

Comment: @Krzysztof you can repeat the setup again. or just hold on to the output of setup alone in a variable and apply returns to that variable

Comment: It would help a lot if you could give some indication as to why you want to do this or what problem you are trying to solve with it.

Comment: @Krzysztof what you are asking for is outside of the feature set for that framework. You could try raising an [issue](https://github.com/moq/moq4/issues) on the project in github. There is not much else that can be done here.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, I didn't  understand question, but here NUnit sample - everything works out of box

```
[TestFixture]
public class TestClass
{
    private const int BASE_VALUE = -1;
    private const int FIRST_MOCK_VALUE = 1;
    private const int SECOND_MOCK_VALUE = 2;

    public class Foo
    {
        public virtual int Bar()
        {
            return BASE_VALUE;
        }
    }

    [Test]
    public void Test()
    {
        var mock = new Mock<Foo>();
        mock.CallBase = true;
        var mockedObject = mock.Object;

        int actualValue = mockedObject.Bar();
        Assert.AreEqual(BASE_VALUE, actualValue);

        mock.Setup(m => m.Bar()).Returns(FIRST_MOCK_VALUE);
        actualValue = mockedObject.Bar();
        Assert.AreEqual(FIRST_MOCK_VALUE, actualValue);

        mock.Setup(m => m.Bar()).Returns(SECOND_MOCK_VALUE);
        actualValue = mockedObject.Bar();
        Assert.AreEqual(SECOND_MOCK_VALUE, actualValue);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

```
int actualValue = mockedObject.Bar();
Assert.AreEqual(BASE_VALUE, actualValue);

int callingCount = 0;
mock.Setup(m => m.Bar())
    .Returns(FIRST_MOCK_VALUE)
    .Callback(() => 
    {
        if (++callingCount == 1)
        {
            mock.Setup(m => m.Bar()).Returns(SECOND_MOCK_VALUE);
        }
    });
actualValue = mockedObject.Bar();
Assert.AreEqual(FIRST_MOCK_VALUE, actualValue);

actualValue = mockedObject.Bar();
Assert.AreEqual(SECOND_MOCK_VALUE, actualValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

The setup method is a call used with

```
System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<T, TResult>>
```

You can use it as parameters and keep the separate expressions in a list or dictionary for easy access.